# The internal speakers of my laptop stop working after an hour or so

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers

Lenovo, Windows 7. It works again after restart ... for now.

It sometimes happens after I use the headphones, so I tried to force disable them from registry ("ForceDisableJD"), as described in [another post](https://superuser.com/questions/439330/no-sound-on-my-laptop-internal-speakers/).

However, It happened again without headphones involved. What can I do more?

Comment: Having the mixer controlling sounds by device and ... by application is an terrifying awful idea :O, I need the simplicity of my ... former laptop

Comment: Clean and test the 3.5mm headphone jack for damage, gunk, loose connections, etc. (you'll need to take the notebook apart and have a continuity tester handy).

Comment: Is this an internal or an external intervention? I hope you don't really suggest to use a turnscrew: not good at that and I am abroad, cannot risk it.

Comment: I do suggest that, because this is SuperUser not AfraidToFixMyOwnComputerUser. ;)  If you're uncomfortable with taking the notebook apart, then I suggest packing it up and taking it to an authorize repair depot.  If you want to narrow it down to hardware vs. software, backup your data and reinstall Windows fresh (or install it fresh on another drive, or try a LiveCD); if it keeps happening, it's more than likely a hardware issue.

Comment: Do you try to plug in the headphones again when this happens? Check if the sound comes from headphones when this happens.

Comment: @Hunter The headphones always work, even when the speakers are "dead" (all the software signs are good: the speakers/mixer visual control "shows" me the music)

Comment: @techie007 I'll try first an external cleaning, I'll be back with details.

Comment: I have 2 "High Definition Audio Device" in "Device Manager": Location 1 and Location 3 (don't know what the location is). 
Following a SuperSuperUser friend advice I reinstalled the audio drivers (location 1) from the producer: [Lenovo G560](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/research/hints-or-tips/detail.page?DocID=HT072731). It seems that it is made by a company named Conexant and with the installer came, of course, some other staff (2 processes: "Conexant Audio Message Service" & "Conexant High Definition Audio Filter Agent"). I almost one this solution to fail to uninstall all this ... staff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer was to have the producer's  drivers (and their additional software - like a dozen of new applications doing almost nothing). After I installed those, everything worked alright. So before internal & external cleaning, first try the soft(ware) solutions (a Linux test would have followed, and only afterwards., as the final solution, the cleaning).